# Gatsby & _headers.json - Is it possible to target wild card target *.ext files?

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-cloud

I would like to add custom headers on specific file extensions when using Gatsby on Gatsby Hosting.

I am trying out the [`gatsby-plugin-gatsby-cloud`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-gatsby-cloud/) plugin, which generates a `_headers.json` file that Gatsby Hosting uses.

As a test, I did the following configuration:

```
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-gatsby-cloud',
      options: {
        headers: {
          '/images/components/PromotionBoxDownloadApp/napp-demo-screens.webp': [
            'X-Test-Omega: MD00',
          ],
          '/images/components/PromotionBoxDownloadApp/*.webp': [
            'X-Test-StarWebp: true',
          ],
          '/images/components/PromotionBoxDownloadApp/*': [
            'X-Test-Star: true',
          ],
          '*.webp': [
            'X-Test-Three: MD33',
          ],
          '/*.webp': [
            'X-Test-Beta: MD11',
          ],
          '/**/*.webp': [
            'X-Test-Gamma: MD22',
          ],
          '/*': [
            'X-Test-Two: MD22',
          ],
        }
      }
```

And then I am fetching the the resource `/images/images/components/PromotionBoxDownloadApp/napp-demo-screens.webp`.

I see that the response headers return the following test headers:

- `X-Test-Omega: MD00`
- `X-Test-Star: true`
- `X-Test-Two: MD22`

Meaning, the following sections worked:

- `'/images/components/PromotionBoxDownloadApp/napp-demo-screens.webp'`
- `'/images/components/PromotionBoxDownloadApp/*'`
- `'/*'`

But it seems like `'/*.webp'` nor `'/**/*.webp'` worked.

Is it not possible to target specific file extensions with `_headers.json`?